# JavaFX: How can I make shining sphere?

Tags: javafx

I'm new in JavaFX and I'am trying to make solar system.
Now, I want to make [sun like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCsDL.png)
I've tried:

```
Glow g = new Glow(100);
sphere.setEffect(g);
```

But it doesn't work.
Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Source**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        // Create a rectangle
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(75, 75);
        rect.setTranslateX(300);
        rect.setTranslateY(-5);
        rect.setTranslateZ(400);

        // Load an image
        rect.setFill(new ImagePattern(new Image("file:spark2.png")));

        // Create a Camera to view the 3D Shapes
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
        camera.setTranslateX(100);
        camera.setTranslateY(-50);
        camera.setTranslateZ(300);

        // Add the Shapes and the Light to the Group
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(rect);
        // Create a Scene with depth buffer enabled
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800, true);
        // Fill the background with black
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        // Add the Camera to the Scene
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        // Add the Scene to the Stage
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // Set the Title of the Stage
        stage.setTitle("An Example");
        // Display the Stage
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Star]

**The sparkle image:**

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDZKE.png)

Comment: I want to do sun shine effect like there -> [link]i.stack.imgur.com/vCsDL.png
(Effect around sun)

Comment: @YozoZChomutova Check my last edit, is this what are you looking for?  
This is a really dead simple star shining texture applied to a rectangle.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'am looking for. How did you do that?